# How to add lines to existing matplotlib figures in a for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am not very familiar with matplotlib and want to add a line to each of the two different plots in each iteration of a for loop. I tried the two things shown in the simplified example below, but both threw errors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.figure()
ax2 = plt.figure()

for i in range(5):
    ## these throw "Can not put single artist in more than one figure" error
    plt.plot([0,i], [0,i], figure=ax1)
    plt.plot([i,0], [i,0], figure=ax2)

    ## these throw "'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'" error
    ax1.plot([0,i], [0,i])
    ax2.plot([i,0], [i,0])
```

Comment: Did you consider `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)`? Then in your loop use `ax[0].plot...` and `ax[1].plot...`. Your error is because you are getting a figure object instead of an axis object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your goal properly, but you are getting an error because you are using figure as if they were axis. You need to declare an axis object that belongs to figures, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure() #figure object
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.gca() #axis object
ax2 = fig2.gca()

for i in range(5):
    ax1.plot([0,i], [0,i])
    ax2.plot([i,0], [i,0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another equivalent way to achieve the desired result is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots() 

for i in range(5):
    ax1.plot([0,i], [0,i])
    ax2.plot([i,0], [i,0])
```